# NSString comparision

Tags: ios, nsstring

The following if condition jumps first time. I print the ozoneString and particleString, then it turns null, but it does not go into the the condition. it jumps.

```
  NSString *ozoneString=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ozoneString"];
  NSString *particleString=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"particleString"];

  NSLog(@"ozone : %@", ozoneString);
  NSLog(@"particle :%@", particleString);

         if ([particleString isEqual:[NSNull null]] 
             ||[particleString isEqualToString:@""]
             ||[ozoneString isEqual:[NSNull null]] 
             ||[ozoneString isEqualToString:@""])
            {
             NSLog(@"I am in");
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your strings are set to `nil`.

Unless you are sure you store an actual `NSNull` value at some point, your check should be:

```
if (ozoneString.length == 0 || particleString.length == 0) {
    NSLog(@"I am in");
}
```

Comment: I like the merging of length call with nil check; interesting how I can't really come up with an equivalently terse version in Swift.

Answer (score 2):

Your strings are `nil`, which is the absence of an object, not `[NSNull null]`, which *is* an object, often used for a placeholder in collections. Try `if(particleString != nil)` or similar.

`nil`, for whatever reason, prints as `(null)`, which is why you see that when you NSLog the strings.

Comment: thanks a lot Jesse, sorry he answered the question first. I upvoted your answer as well.